# How to force Windows file explorer to display files that have invalid names?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, encoding, filenames

I was searching journals on a research topic. I eventually got to some old exotic site containing a zip file which according to the description contained multiple documents. However when I unzipped it with file explorer the folder was empty. I tried multiple times but everytime I got zero files. I first thought Windows Defender was automatically quarantining the files but there were no such logs.

After a few attempts I gave up and booted up my Ubuntu desktop. When I downloaded the same zip there I realized what was happening. The files inside the zip were created decades ago and they were using an archaic encoding. Their names contained special characters not permitted in Windows. Thanks to Linux's relaxed rules they were visible on Ubuntu. When I went back to Windows and used a 3rd party file manager I could see and even open the files just fine.

This means that Windows does not automatically remove invalid files, but file explorer is set in a way that does not display them. Is there a registry key or other switch that I can flip so that File Explorer does display such files?

Comment: I believe that you are interpreting what you are seeing incorrectly.  We need more information.  Windows makes files through a call to "CreateFile()" which will not allow an invalid file name (period).  You say "3rd party file manager" but don't say which one.  Your 3rd party file manager might be virtualizing the contents of that zip file by showing you what is in it.  It doesn't mean the file exists on windows with that name.  Please provide more specifics than "archaic encoding" and "3rd party file manager". You have me (and probably others) intrigued :-).

Comment: No, there is not, and I'm not sure that Explorer is actually extracting the files like you think. When I view a folder containing files/folders with invalid characters those are replaced by boxes or question marks. Are you perhaps not seeing Hidden Files? When you extract the file using 7zip, does Explorer still not see the files, or are the invalid characters just replaced?

Comment: @music2myear .. I was more thinking of true invalid chars .. as in "I?am*Bob|TheFile.txt" .. not chars outside of the printable range.  I completely agree with you.  I myself think OP should OPEN with 7zip and show what the 7zip GUI shows in addition to a 7zip file extraction.

Comment: True, there's some characters it'll just fail on. I was thinking the same thing you were saying as I was writing my comment as you posted yours, that OP is making some wrong assumptions about what they're observing. But I would expect the extractor to report an error if it came across a character it couldn't handle, which makes me wonder if some of the files are possibly hidden as well.

Comment: Maybe you could try winrar with "Automatically Rename" option enabled...